# Putty Event Log

Tags: encryption, authentication, cryptography

Can anyone explain me the Step by step process of Key Exchange that takes place while accessing Linux machine using Putty ? I found the Event Log of Putty but the Various Key Exchange didn't make very sense to me. I am still a beginner in security field. So,anyone please help remove my doubt ?

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4432.txt

Comment: @LucasKauffman : Thanks Lucas for the share. I also have a doubt regarding the public key sharing. [link](http://www2.kinneret.ac.il/mjmay/ise334/334-Assignment2-CipherHashes.pdf) I found above page that explain AES Key Exchange very well. When the Key Fingerprint is passed on to the client side form server side, the client must have the public key of the server to validate the fingerprint. So by looking at the above page could you please explain me at which step this Public key has been exchanged. Considering first time communication.